# insert multiple checkboxes to laravel 5 database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I want to store multiple checkboxes from a form to database.

```
    &nbsp{!! Form::checkbox('expectations[]','New anerobic routines',true); !!} Find new anerobic routines <br>
 &nbsp{!! Form::checkbox('expectations[]','New aerobic routines',true); !!} Find new aerobic routines <br>
 &nbsp{!! Form::checkbox('expectations[]','Follow',true); !!}
```

I won't need these values later for viewing . Basically it would be for using them later for showing user data based on this data.

What's your suggestion to do so?

I already have the store method in the controller ready to insert data to db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea for saving the values would be on json to column if you only need to view the data to user but not check via json column something like this  `{['key','value'],['key','value']}`

Comment: That's pretty general.
I now have a code that work well - except it does not insert data to database. can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: doesnot insert the json value in database?